# AWS CDK Api Gateway MTLS ownershipVerificationCertificate for imported certificates on ACM

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk, mtls, aws-acm

when creating a restapi API Gateway using AWS CDK, I used an imported certificate in ACM for the `certificate` field inside the `domainName` property. This raises an error which says

```
Missing ownershipVerificationCertificate
```

However, on CDK it doesn't seem to have a field for me to provide this ownershipVerificationCertificate. Any way I for this to be solved without manually creating the custom domain name through AWS console?

I have tried going through the AWS documentation, as well as attempt importing the domainName

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Please add a minimal code example to your question.